# Configure sails.js not to cache the response

Tags: node.js, caching, sails.js

I have an application on node.js using sails.js as a framework. For displaying the informations to the user I have implemented some .ejs files.
When navigating using links within the app menu, I receive a "304 - Nod Modified" response. Also, within headers in the response I see **Etag**, **If-None-Match** or **Expires**.
After reading some posts, I have added the **"app.disable('etag')"** statement within /config/**express.js** file in the **customMiddleware** function and etag and if-none-match are not sent anymore.
Anyway, now I do not see any request made to the server (just the first one is made) when accessing different pages (not even 304 response).
How can I tell sails.js to stop caching my pages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add this to a policy instead and then just apply it to the specific pages/requests you want - if you do not want to set this for the entire application.

/api/policies/nocache.js:

```
/**
 * Sets no-cache header in response.
 */
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    sails.log.info("Applying disable cache policy");
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');  
    next();
};
```

Comment: This looks very good, actually. My next goal is to find a way to only do this in the `development` environment under `config/env`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding the code below solved my problem:

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
res.header('Expires', '-1');
res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
```

These line should be included in the **customMiddleware** function from the /config/**express.js** file.

If there is a cleaner way to achieve the same result, please reply.

Comment: A better way to achieve the same result but only for specific pages can be done as @c1freitas has previously mentioned.