# Update EJS Layout with Session

Tags: node.js, session, express, ejs, express-session

My ejs layout provides the current user's username on the main menu through sessions

```
            <a href="">
          <% if (typeof currentUser === 'undefined'){%>
            <% } else { %>
            <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
            <% } %>

        </a>
```

Now when I destroy the session and redirect to the main page, the currentUser's infomation is still showing, although logging currentuser returns undefined.  Is there a way to force the layout to update itself to show current information?

Comment: Have you tried disabling caching of views?

Comment: didnt know i could do that. how do you?

Comment: I'm not sure if view caching will help, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352742/configure-sails-js-not-to-cache-the-response) definitely should. For ejs caching options, refer to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) and set an item limit of 0.